# tilemap collision not working like it should

Tags: javascript

I have tilemap collision sorted out... kinda. Some tiles react great. Others, not so much. It is really inconsistent if it hits and from what direction, also, it has created some sort of barrier once x hits around 480ish where it stops.
here is the jsfiddle so you can take a look at what I am talking about
http://jsfiddle.net/t0ahc5qa/
as you can see some blocks it just phases through, while others it doesn't.
here is where collisions are taken note of.

```
function checkmove(x,y){
  if(mapArray[Math.floor(x/tileWidth)][Math.floor(y/tileHeight)]==1 ||
    mapArray[Math.ceil(x/tileWidth)][Math.floor(y/tileHeight)]==1 ||
    mapArray[Math.floor(x/tileWidth)][Math.ceil(y/tileHeight)]==1 ||
    mapArray[Math.ceil(x/tileWidth)][Math.ceil(y/tileHeight)]==1){
            console.log('hit');

     return false;
 } else {

return true;
}
if(mapArray[Math.floor(x/tileWidth)][Math.floor(y/tileHeight)]==2 ||
mapArray[Math.ceil(x/tileWidth)][Math.floor(y/tileHeight)]==2 ||
mapArray[Math.floor(x/tileWidth)][Math.ceil(y/tileHeight)]==2 ||
mapArray[Math.ceil(x/tileWidth)][Math.ceil(y/tileHeight)]==2){
    console.log('lava');

 return false;
} else {

return true;
}

}
```

if you have any ways to improve the collision, please feel free to, I am looking for any way to make it not so buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your x and y variables switched inside the loops of the `render()` function.

```
context.drawImage(tile1, y*tileWidth,x*tileHeight,tileWidth,tileHeight);
```

should be

```
context.drawImage(tile1, x*tileWidth,y*tileHeight,tileWidth,tileHeight);
```

Comment: Thank you man, you're awesome, can believe I didn't think to look at that.